# Не получается очистить ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-search-view

Есть строка поиска её вывод отображается в `ListView` (По-мере написания отображается та или иная ссылка)Но после того как ты нашел что тебе нужно  и удалил запись со строки поиска нужно очистить `ListView` при помощи `lv.setadapter(null);`
Реализовал следующим путем :

```
  sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                if(query.length==0){
                  'lv.setadapter(null);'
}
                  SenderReceiver sr=new SenderReceiver(MainActivity.this,urlAddress,query,lv,noDataImg,noNetworkImg);
                    sr.execute();
                    return false;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                      if(query.length==0){
                  'lv.setadapter(null);'
            }
                  SenderReceiver sr = new SenderReceiver(MainActivity.this, urlAddress, query, lv, noDataImg, noNetworkImg);
                        sr.execute();
                        return false;

                }
            });
```

Но ничего не происходит ...

```
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                if(query.length==0){
                 lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Попробуйте обновить adapter, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Нет тоже не сработало .Я просто уверен что услов задал неправльно но где ошибка понять немогу

Comment: А что вы передаете в параметры adapter?

Comment: я должен убрать listview

Comment: а то после поиска он остается с запросами а зачем мне это я хочу чтоб после поиска все обнулялось как то так

Comment: напишите так, где хотите скрыть. `lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);` надеюсь поможет!

Comment: нет не работает

Comment: Покажите код где вы инициализируете.

Comment: Попробуйте проверить таким образом 
`if(query.isEmpty()){
                 lv.setVisibility(View.GONE); `

Comment: Спасибо кронус!а почему сработал твй метод а мой не рботал ????

Comment: напиши в виде ответа взу свой вариант я его отмечу как правльный

Comment: Точно не помню почему, может потому что даже `String str = ""` по моему какое то значение возвращает.
Можно было бы еще проверить так, думаю сработало бы.  `query.trim().length() == 0)`

Comment: аа понятноо стало

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте проверить таким образом

```
if(query.isEmpty())
{ lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```